# add values from arrays to an array?

Tags: php, arrays

how do i add values from arrays to an array so that it grows by time.

eg.

```
all values form array1 to myArray.

all values form array2 to myArray.
```

so now myArray contains all values from 1 and 2.

i want to do this in a cpu efficient way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use the **[`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)** function (also see **[`array_merge_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php)**):

```
$myArray = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

> If the input arrays have the **same
>   string keys**, then **the later value for
>   that key will overwrite the previous
>   one**. If, however, the arrays contain
>   numeric keys, the later value will not
>   overwrite the original value, but will
>   be appended.

---

Or use the **[Union Array Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php)** (**`+`**):

```
$myArray = $array1 + $array2;
```

> The + operator appends elements of
>   remaining keys from the right handed
>   array to the left handed, whereas
>   **duplicated keys are NOT overwritten**.

Answer (score 4):

```
$myArray = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

See the [documentation](https://www.php.net/array_merge), as there are a few things you will want to know about how duplicates and numerical keys are handled.